# Why do I get this "attempt to call a table value" when iterating through a table?

Tags: lua, lua-table, garrys-mod

I'm trying to find the key associated with the value of a table in Garry's mod Lua, but I'm getting an error as though it's not a table.

This is part of a larger solution to a game crashing bug on someone else's code that I'm maintaining/fixing.

long story short, I need to get the number of a key based on what value it is. a simple, short code that has this issue:

```lua
function starttest()
     local tbl = {"a", "b", "c"}

     local printme = FindValueInTable(tbl, "c")

print(printme)

end

function FindValueInTable(table, value)
     for k, v in table do --errors on this line saying "attempt to call a table value"
          if v == value then
               return k
          end
     end
     return nil
end
```

I'm stumped on what to do here because `table` is literally a table, How can the `for k,v in table` really be failing?

The result I'm expecting is for it to return the numerical key that has the value in `value`. so if `value == "c"` and `table[3]` happens to have the value `"c"` then it should return `3` as a result.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal complete script that can be used to reproduce the problem. Often you'll find the solution yourself when you try to come up with the minimal script.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko I have now heavily edited the post to do exactly that. I didn't find a solution in doing so, however.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bizzare "attempt to call a table value" in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350281/bizzare-attempt-to-call-a-table-value-in-lua)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `for k, v in ipairs(table) do` instead of `for k, v in table do`, as this form of the `for` loop expects an iterator after `in`, so tries to "call" your `table` variable, which leads to the error.

As discussed in the comments, you may need to use `pairs` instead of `ipairs` if you have have non-numerical or non-sequential indices in the table.

Comment: Why `ipairs()`?

Comment: Because it appears to be sufficient in this case.

Comment: marking as the answer; cause something very similar solved it. not ``ipairs`` in my case, given im using slightly different lua for gmod, but just ``pairs()`` works fine.